# How do I use hook_update_N() to create a vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I want to create a standard vocabulary (no extra fields) in Drupal 8.7.5 programatically, using hook_update_N. I've never used this function before. So I'm a complete newbie.

I've modified a simple delete script I was shown, but something tells me it can't possibly be this simple.

Here's my starting point:

```
<?php

use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary;

/**
 * create vocabulary testname.
 */
function ent_create_update_8105(&$sandbox) {
  $vid = 'testname';
  $vocabulary = Vocabulary::load($vid);
  if (!$vocabulary) {
    $vocabulary->create();
  }
}
```

I assume that, once the script is created correctly, I simply run `drush entup`.

Comment: _I assume that, once the script is created correctly, I simply run `drush entup`._ `entup` was removed, run `drush updb` to perform updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code, you should be able to create a new vocabulary.

```php
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary;

/**
 * Create the testname vocabulary.
 */
function ent_create_update_8105(&$sandbox) {
  $vid = 'testname';

  if (!$vocabulary = Vocabulary::load($vid)) {
    $vocabulary = Vocabulary::create([
      'vid' => $vid,
      'description' => '',
      'name' => 'The vocabulary name',
    ]);

    $vocabulary->save();
  }
}
```

The correct hook to use to create or change entities is not [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.9.x), though, but [`hook_post_update_NAME()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_post_update_NAME/8.9.x).

The hook must be added to the *ent.post_update.php* file, not the *ent.install* file. For the rest, the code is pretty much similar.

```php
/**
 * Create the testname vocabulary.
 */
function ent_post_update_create_vocabulary(&$sandbox) {
  $vid = 'testname';

  if (!$vocabulary = Vocabulary::load($vid)) {
    $vocabulary = Vocabulary::create([
      'vid' => $vid,
      'description' => '',
      'name' => 'The vocabulary name',
    ]);

    $vocabulary->save();
  }
}
```